# lend me an ear?

Tags: ambience, soundscapes

hi everyone,

i'm new here to the forum as well as the sound design field in general. been experimenting with some soundscapes of my own, bumbling about in my own way, and was wondering if anyone can lend me an ear for some professional advice on mixing and EQ. i'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to these things, so if anyone can give me a few tips based on this listen i would greatly appreciate it. i put a link below to stream my little driftosphere. thanks in advance.

http://www.archive.org/details/DolefulDram

-ted houghtaling

Answer (score 3):

Hi Ted, and welcome to SSD!

Happy to see that you are experimenting with sound and learning as you go. I listened to your track and have a few comments. Please take them with a few grains of salt, for as you know, these types of things are quite subjective. My notes by minutes:seconds :

- 0:00  Interesting sounds! Enjoyed
  them for a while…
- 0:45  Became quite bored of the same
  sounds…
- 2:03  Was glad for the change! The
  introduction to this second part was
  very cool, gritty and aggressive.
  Quite evocative.
- 2:35  Became bored again. The same
  sound qualities I heard at 2:03 were
  still going and I didn't understand
  why they weren't evolving…
- 4:43  Again, glad for the change, but
  not into this vibe. Dunno why, sounds
  too "drab" for my tastes. Lost
  interest.
- 5:25  The choir swell brought me back
  into the piece again, but not for
  long. Perhaps a cleaner sound? This
  one is quite dull and muddy, hard to
  discern what is going on. Maybe you
  took the lo-fi approach on purpose.
- 6:22  Fade out into spacey darkness.
  Neat ending.

Keep experimenting! And please continue allowing the folks on SSD to listen to your work; I believe you'll usually find a receptive bunch who are happy to offer their expertise.